# Transitioning from Stemmed to unstemmed field in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am working with SOLR (3.x) and need to transition a field from a stemmed to an unstemmed version.

Is there a stemming filter that will index both the exact text as well as stemmed text (so I can match on both in the near term) or am I forced to copy to a new field and then transition to the new field.

Comment: copyField is the only way to go. Execute your query like `q=unstemmed_field:querystring OR stemmed_field:querystring`

Answer (score 8):

from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

> A repeated question is "how can I have the original term contribute more to the score than the stemmed version"? In Solr 4.3, the KeywordRepeatFilterFactory has been added to assist this functionality. This filter emits two tokens for each input token, one of them is marked with the Keyword attribute. Stemmers that respect keyword attributes will pass through the token so marked without change. So the effect of this filter would be to index both the original word and the stemmed version. The 4 stemmers listed above all respect the keyword attribute.
>
> For terms that are not changed by stemming, this will result in duplicate, identical tokens in the document. This can be alleviated by adding the RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory.

```
<fieldType name="text_keyword" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilter"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This will match your exact term and stemmed version both. Though for exact term, the score is going to be high as both unstemmed and stemmed version will be matched and scores added.

We have used this before but then moved on to creating two fields (exactly as Arun's comment), stemmed and unstemmed, searching in both simultaneously and providing boosts as we need it. This gives us more control on what we are doing.

Just another option, see what suits you.